# Struct member edition from included file

Tags: c

My file structure looks like this:

- primaryFile.h
- primaryFile.c
- secondaryFile.h
- secondaryFile.c

primaryFile.h has:

```
#include secondaryFile.h

typedef struct{ secondaryStruct member} primaryStruct;
extern primaryStruct pStruct
```

secondaryFile.h has:

```
typedef struct{ uint8_t member} secondaryStruct;
```

Now I want to edit `pStruct.member` in `secondaryFile.c`. But if I included `secondaryFile.h` in `primaryFile.h` I can't include it back now. What am I supposed to do to edit `pStruct` in `secondaryStruct.c`?

Comment: Do your header files have include guards? You better share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: They both do have include guards #ifndef #define

Comment: What does "include back" mean? Why do you need it?

Comment: It means. I used #include "secondaryFile.h"  in primaryFile.h. Now I want to edit struct that is extern in primaryFile.h inside secondaryFile.c. So I want to do #include "primaryFile.h" in secondaryFile.h. When I do that. Typedef secondaryStruct stops working for primaryStruct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
I'm just dumb, I should have done `#include "primaryFile.h"` in `secondyFile.c` not in `.h` in order to modify struct members.